# How get data from ajax object in controller Laravel?

Tags: ajax, laravel

In ajax I have 3 objects 'emp_info, leave_detail, and leave_items' in controller I don't know how to get record of each object. Could you help me please?

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/leave-request-initiator/store',
        data: {_token: $('#_token').val(), emp_info: $('#frm_emp_info').serialize(), leave_detail: $('#frm_leave_detail').serialize(), leave_items: leave_items},
        beforeSend: function () {
            console.log('sending');
        },
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
```

Controller.

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();
        foreach ($data->emp_info as $item){
            $empcode = $item['EMPCODE'];
        }

        $leaveDetail = new HREmpLeave([
            'EMPCODE' => $empcode,
            'LEAVECODE' => $request->get('LEAVECODE'),
            'FROMDATE' => $request->get('FROMDATE'),
            'TODATE' => $request->get('TODATE'),
            'BACKTOWORKON' => $request->get('BACKTOWORKON'),
            'NODAY' => $request->get('NODAY'),
            'REMARK1' => $request->get('REMARK1')
        ]);
        $leaveDetail->save();
    }
```

Comment: Any error codes / browser network inspector / html you could add to the post?

Comment: It show the error like this in console sorry I am a student I just learn it.

POST http://localhost:8000/leave-request-initiator/store 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ 10009:335
dispatch @ jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3
q.handle @ jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3

Comment: So many thing is wrong in this code: first $data is an array how come you access it with `$data->emp_info` 2. in the foreach (even if that was possible) only the last item will get set to $empcode, is that your intention?

Comment: What is `$('#frm_emp_info')`, `$('#frm_leave_detail')` are they forms on their own or just an input element?

Comment: Yes it is forms on their own I have three forms.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
  $data = $request->all();
  foreach ($data->emp_info as $item){
        $empcode = $item['EMPCODE'];
  }
```

to this:

```
$emp_info = parse_str($request->emp_info); //parse into a array
$empcode = $emp_info['EMPCODE'];
```

Comment: it doesn't error but $empcode is null after I try your code.

Comment: it means you should be sure you have the 'EMPCODE' as one of the fields in your `$('#frm_emp_info')` form.